# Why delete in Oracle takes more time than select also in case 0 rows?

Tags: oracle, temp, segment

I run simple query:

```
 select * from tableA where fk in (select pk from tableB where column='somevalue')
```

It returns 0 rows and takes time near 20 seconds
But when I run:

```
 delete from tableA where fk in (select pk from tableB where column='somevalue')
```

It takes time near 3 minutes and produces error: cannot extend temp segment!
But it is nonsense: delete query deletes nothing!
How to workaround this?

Comment: Honestly, I find this hard to believe - are you 100% sure these are the exact queries you've been running? Did someone change the data of tableA / tableB between your queries?

Comment: How many rows does your sub select return (`select count(*) from tableB where column='somevalue'`)?

Comment: please alias the tables and then prefix any column the respective alias.

Comment: sub select could return near 10 mln records

Comment: Is there an `on delete` trigger on `tableA`?

Comment: Please post the explain plans of both statements

Comment: Maybe you have some FK constraints on un-indexed columns?

Comment: there are no triggers, no foreign key constraints on un-indexed columns. Only one guess - may be the problem is in small temp segment - 512Mb?

Comment: Post the explain plan. It's possible that the optimiser is using a different plan to execute the subquery in each case; perhaps the DELETE is first trying to execute the subquery on tableB first and materialize it in memory, before it accesses tableA.